# Why is scipy.io.loadmat failing to filter out variables on all but the first iteration of this generator function?

Tags: python, scipy

If we consider the following generator function ...

```
def loadrun(runs, varnames=None):
    for fle in runs:
        yield loadmat(fle, variable_names=varnames)
```

which we call as follows ...

```
vnames = ['targetpos', 'cuepos', 'soa', 'response']
trials = loadrun(datafiles, vnames)  # datafiles is a list of paths to files
```

we get the following output when listing the length of the resulting dict:

```
[in] for t in trials:
         print len(t)

[out] 7
      128
      128
      128
      128
      128
      128
      128
```

All `.mat` files contain 124 variables, so only the first output is correct.  What gives?

**EDIT**

I further reduced the scope of the problem.  It seems as though `loadmat`'s `variable_names` field fails after the first iteration in **any loop**.  Any idea what's going on here?

```
for df in datafiles:
    print len(loadmat(df, variable_names=vnames))

[out] 7
      128
      128
      128
      128
      128
      128
      128
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `'__'` is in any of the keys of `t`?

Comment: unutbu, yes, but I don't think that's where the trouble lies.  Those variables actually *are* filtered out correctly.  The problem is with `scipy.io.loadmat` not **only** retrieving the variables I ask for.  In fact, I'll remove that line from the question since the bug is reproducible without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.io.loadmat` is being naughty<sup>[1]</sup> and *mutating* the list passed to `variable_names`. After the first call to `loadmat`, `varnames` is the empty list.

You can workaround this by defining a temporary variable, `_varnames`:

```
def loadrun(runs, varnames = None):
    for fle in runs:
        _varnames = None if varnames is None else varnames[:]
        yield sio.loadmat(fle, variable_names = _varnames)
```

---

For example:

```
import string
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
datafiles = ['/tmp/data{i:d}.mat'.format(i = i) for i in range(3)]

def loadrun(runs, varnames = None):
    for fle in runs:
        _varnames = None if varnames is None else varnames[:]
        yield sio.loadmat(fle, variable_names = _varnames)

def create_datafiles():
    for filename in datafiles:
        arr = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
        mdict = {letter : arr for letter in letters}
        sio.savemat(filename, mdict = mdict)

create_datafiles()
vnames = ['a', 'c', 'd']
trials = loadrun(datafiles, vnames)
for t in trials:
    print(t.keys())
```

---

Actually, it appears the problem originates in both mio4.py and mio5.py, where `MatFile4Reader` and `MatFile5Reader` calls the `remove` method on `variable_names`:

```
def get_variables(self, variable_names=None):
    while not self.end_of_stream():
        ...
        if variable_names:
            variable_names.remove(name)
            if len(variable_names) == 0:
                break
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response!  I'll give this a whirl.  Has a bug report been filed for this, or did you just discover this?